# TPOT machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, regression, pipelines

I trained a regression [TPOT algorithm](https://epistasislab.github.io/tpot/) on Google Colab, where the output of the TPOT process is some boiler plate Python code as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, make_union
from tpot.builtins import StackingEstimator
from tpot.export_utils import set_param_recursive

# NOTE: Make sure that the outcome column is labeled 'target' in the data file
tpot_data = pd.read_csv('PATH/TO/DATA/FILE', sep='COLUMN_SEPARATOR', dtype=np.float64)
features = tpot_data.drop('target', axis=1)
training_features, testing_features, training_target, testing_target = \
            train_test_split(features, tpot_data['target'], random_state=1)

# Average CV score on the training set was: -4.881434802676966
exported_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    StackingEstimator(estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(bootstrap=False, max_features=0.9000000000000001, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=20, n_estimators=100)),
    ExtraTreesRegressor(bootstrap=True, max_features=0.9000000000000001, min_samples_leaf=6, min_samples_split=13, n_estimators=100)
)
# Fix random state for all the steps in exported pipeline
set_param_recursive(exported_pipeline.steps, 'random_state', 1)

exported_pipeline.fit(training_features, training_target)
results = exported_pipeline.predict(testing_features)
```

Would anyone know what is the Sklearn pipeline process like how does this work? When I butter up the boiler plate code and run it with my data set in IPython I can see this output from the pipeline process, ***what is this all doing?***

```
Pipeline(steps=[('stackingestimator-1',
                 StackingEstimator(estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(max_features=0.6500000000000001,
                                                                 min_samples_leaf=19,
                                                                 min_samples_split=14,
                                                                 random_state=1))),
                ('maxabsscaler', MaxAbsScaler()),
                ('stackingestimator-2',
                 StackingEstimator(estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(max_features=0.4,
                                                                 min_samples_leaf=3,
                                                                 min_samples_split=7,
                                                                 random_state=1))),
                ('adaboostregressor',
                 AdaBoostRegressor(learning_rate=0.001, loss='exponential',
                                   n_estimators=100, random_state=1))])
```

The results look good just curious about how the pipelines processes work, any tips or links to tutorials greatly appreciated. I thought this [machinelearningmastery tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tpot-for-automated-machine-learning-in-python/) is also somewhat useful for anyone interested in learning more about TPOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `StackingEstimator` is surprisingly poor, but it's relatively simple: fit the `estimator` on the data, and tack its predictions onto the dataset as a new feature.  [Source](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/blob/6448bdb71ba08b4a0447c640d2f05a05e1affc21/tpot/builtins/stacking_estimator.py#L31), [github issue](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/issues/690).

So, your pipeline fits an `ExtraTreesRegressor` on the original inputs, and appends its predictions to the dataset going forward.  The data (original + 1st predictions) get scaled, then another `ExtraTreesRegressor` is fit (on scaled original and 1st preds, and with different hyperparameters), *its* predictions also getting tacked onto the dataset.  Finally, an `AdaBoostRegressor` is fit on scaled-original + scaled-1st-preds + 2nd-preds.